# Simplest way to split human name in postgres?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

Consider a table with full human names:

```sql
create table names (full_name varchar not null);   
insert into names (full_name) 
  values ('Jane Marie Doe'), ('John Doe');
```

In postgres, what is the **simplest** (most readable) way to split the names into first and last?

```
 first_name | last_name 
------------+-----------
 Jane Marie | Doe
 John       | Doe
(2 rows)
```

This is what I came up with, but it seems really complicated. Surely there's a simpler way?

```sql
select 
  array_to_string(ary[1:len - 1], ' ') as first_name, 
  ary[len] as last_name 
from (
  select ary, array_length(ary, 1) as len
  from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(full_name, E'\\s+') as ary 
    from names
  ) sub1
) sub2;
```

Comment: Your table design is wrong. You should rather be having 2 columns first_name and last_name.

Comment: Re: "Your table design is wrong".  I agree, I'm migrating an existing table to a two-column design, thanks.

Comment: I'd actually say that your original table design is better, not everyone has [first and last names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Anyway, what are you going to do if you have Robert J. Van de Graaff or Pancakes McGee Jr. in your table?

Comment: I agree @muistooshort but my boss (my client) has *decided* that everyone *does* have first and last names.  Fiat culture.

Comment: Then your boss will get the incorrect data they deserve =D

Comment: @Rahul Actually, I completely disagree. This is a correct and sensible design and you should leave it exactly how it is. You are taking a correct schema and breaking it. You just need a "name" field.

Comment: @CraigRinger, You may but I too can't agree with you that it's a good design. Till date I have seen design where name field gets separated to FN and LN and so it gives ease in getting the full name as well getting partial and you don't need to split or use regex likewise in this scenario.

Comment: @Rahul Lots of other things are easy but wrong, too. Like string concatenation into SQL. The right way is harder. I have a friend whose legal full name is "M²" (M-squared). Another whose legal full name is "PRK". Yes, really, I'm not making them up for examples, I hang out with a bunch of ornery geeks, and they won't mind my using their names as examples here - in fact they'll approve. At my work we have team members with family names like `van de Plat` (name changed, but the form is the same). If you see the name `Alan van de Plat`, what's your code going to do? It'll be wrong.

Comment: Just as a reference, the publishing industry has a long established problem in publicly communicating names, especially in an international environment, and the publishing "ONIX" XML standard now specifies eight components: <TitlesBeforeNames>, <NamesBeforeKey>, <PrefixToKey>, <KeyNames>, <NamesAfterKey>, <SuffixToKey>, <LettersAfterNames>, <TitlesAfterNames>. It allows such name components as "van", "Jr", "His Holiness", "MBA FRCS", "Ibrahim" etc. to be precisely specified. Oh and then if you're wise you'll add "Pronunciation Guide" and other preferences to that.

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array(full_name, E'\\s\\S+') as ary
```

instead, as that should split on the last space consistently. Then you know there will only be two members of `ary`

EDIT:
On further reflection, I think the best approach might be to use

```
SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'\s\S+','') as first_name
SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'.+[\s]','') as last_name
```

Comment: Good idea, but your pattern (`E'\\s\\S+$'`) includes the last name in the delimiter, so the second element of the returned array would be the empty string.  This would work for finding the first name, though.

Comment: Handling of items with more than one space is weird. For example `DR SOMIDDHO DEBNATH MD` produces `DR DEBNATH MD` + `MD`.

Comment: SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'(.+)\s\S+$','\1') as first_name 
SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'.+[\s]','') as last_name

Answer (score 4):

For the record, [the current design is correct, and you shouldn't change it](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

If you attempt to do so the *only* vaguely right way to do it is *ask each user what their name parts are*. If you wish you can attempt to guess this for simple-looking two part names, but even then you don't know if "kim seolhyun" is "Kim, Seolhyun" or "Seolhyun, Kim".

A company I worked with did a name split recently. They did it in the least-awful way I've yet seen:

- Sent email to all their users telling them about it in advance
- Changed the "name" field to "preferred display name"
- Added new "Given Name" and "Family Name" fields, avoiding the confusing trap of calling them "first" and "last" names
- Added a new field "Alternate name(s)" for people who have anglicised and native-language names, transliterated and original charset names, etc
- Attempted to guess for simple-looking names, left the rest unchanged
- Sent email to their users to offer them a page they could use to check the name split (if guessed) or enter their name parts (if not guessed).
- Made it clear that if you only have one name you can enter it in the given name field and leave family name blank. Did not enforce family name.
- Did not make *any* attempt to validate names. Your name is `~~M^2`? Good for you, you're weird.
- Did not enforce capitalization, spaces, etc. Names like `de Vinh` are fine
- Did not screw up their text encoding handling.

Basically, any attempt to use regex to split names is wrong.  If you really insist on doing it, do it only for names that "look" simple, e.g.

```
SELECT regexp_matches('Fred Smith', '^([A-Z][[:alpha:]]+) ([A-Z][[:alpha:]]+)$');
```

which will only match names that have two obvious parts, both beginning with a capital letter, and contain only letters (accented or not). Even then, it doesn't solve the "given family" or "family given" problem. Other names won't match, and should be left as-is for the user to change.

Comment: This is really informative, but strictly speaking not an answer to the question. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it with string functions. Find the first space from the end and select it as `last name` and then `replace` the `last name` string in the original string with `''`.

```
with lname as 
(select name, 
reverse(substr(reverse(name),1,strpos(reverse(name),' '))) as last_name
from names)
select replace(name,last_name,'') as first_name, last_name
from lname
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get first name and the rest of the name separately:

```sql
select regexp_replace('John Martin Doe','\\s.*','') as first_name, regexp_replace('John Martin Doe','[a-zA-Z]+','') as last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer has the correct regex for last name.  For first name it is not accurate for the sample the OP provided like "Jane Marie Doe".  You need a regex with a capturing group:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'(.+)\s\S+$','\1') as first_name 
SELECT regexp_replace(full_name,'.+[\s]','') as last_name
```