# Splitting Full Name into First Name and Last Name : (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table below with names of the customer

```
fullname
Ash Ketchum
Mary Joe Keth
John
```

I want to split it into first and last names

```
firstname   lastname
Ash          Ketchum
Mary Joe     Keth
John
```

I referred to this post and tried all the solution but nothing seems to work for me. I already did the same exercise in SQLServer using CHARINDEX() but seems like it's not supported in redshift
, same is the case with SUBSTR()

[Simplest way to split human name in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488398/simplest-way-to-split-human-name-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`SPLIT_PART()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
SPLIT_PART(fullname, ' ', 1) as first_name,
SPLIT_PART(fullname, ' ', 2) as last_name
```