# How to add additional user metadata upon login with Google using Supabase Auth?

Tags: nuxt.js, supabase

I would like to get the first name and last name from the logged in user's Google profile. Upon checking, Google is using `givenName` and `familyName`. Is it possible to only do this with Supabase alone or will I need to use the Google API for this after getting the access token? It says on the [Supabase docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithoauth) but I'm not sure how to do this since I haven't used the Google API as of yet.

I have read the [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and saw it is going to be deprecated next month so I would like to know what is the best approach for this moving forward.

I'm using the Supabase module for Nuxt 3:

```js
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
const accessToken = ref('');

const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "google",
      options: {
        redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/app/home",
        scopes: "openid profile email",
      },
    });
    if (error) throw error;
    accessToken.value = data.session.provider_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error logging in with Google: ", error);
  }
};
```

I followed their User Management Starter to handle the user metadata upon login using the `handle_new_user` function:

```sql
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, full_name, first_name, last_name, username, avatar_url)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'username', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url');
  return new;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can achieve this with Supabase alone, but [it's an undocumented feature](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/964) right now.

For the time being, you can (nearly) achieve what you want with Supabase. Actually, you already *have* achieved it, as good as it gets with current Supabase features, in your current `handle_new_user` function:

> I followed their User Management Starter to handle the user metadata upon login using the `handle_new_user` function

This function makes the full name metadata transferred from Google Accounts available to you in column `public.profiles.full_name`. First and last name are not available individually, though. (Side note: a good explanation of the details how this `handle_new_user` trigger function works is [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32488398).)

#### Why your existing solution is as good as it gets with current Supabase

This kind of metadata transfer is handled in the [Supabase gotrue](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue) project in the `gotrue/api/provider/*.go` files. Compare for example [gotrue issue #127](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/pull/127), where they extended the metadata transferred from Twitter and Github.

Now when you look at [google.go l. 68](https://github.com/dsumer/gotrue/blob/9eebf9c/api/provider/google.go#L68), you see currently two pieces of user metadata are transferred for a login with Google:

```
data := &UserProvidedData{
    Metadata: map[string]string{
        nameKey:      u.Name,
        avatarURLKey: u.AvatarURL,
    },
}
```

`nameKey` and `avatarURLKey` are [defined in `provider.go`](https://github.com/dsumer/gotrue/blob/9eebf9c/api/provider/provider.go#L10) like this:

```
const (
    userNameKey  = "user_name"
    avatarURLKey = "avatar_url"
    nameKey      = "full_name"
    aliasKey     = "slug"
)
```

So these are the same JSON field names used in your existing `handle_new_user` function, which transfers metadata to your `public.profiles` table.

#### Alternative solutions

The downside of the solution above, for your usecase, is that `first_name` and `last_name` are not provided, only `full_name`. This leaves you with four options in total:

1. **Work with only the full name.** This would be my preferred solution, as [not everyone has a firstname and lastname anyway](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Plus, if your software always uses firstname and lastname together anyway, then it does not need to know about any potential sub-structuring of a full name.
2. **Split `full_name`** yourself into first and last name. This could be achieved with a modification to the `handle_new_user` function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32488398) how to approach this in PostgreSQL. But really, it's better to work with the full name, as automatic splitting will always make mistakes.
3. **Extend Supabase.** If you are self-hosting Supabase for your software, you can make the necessary adaptations to their [gotrue](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue) component so that more metadata is delivered from a Google user on login. Supabase is open source after all. You can also provide your changes in a pull request back to Supabase and hope they will include them into the official version, but this is not guaranteed of course.
4. **Use the Google API** [Google Identity Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) yourself to get `givenName` and `familyName`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide me with this much info! I also saw you posted an issue on Supabase's repo. I guess I would have to work with only the full name for now. The target audience of the app I'm working on is solely in my country where people have two first names and two last names, so splitting the full name isn't a good solution.